# iphone play video in a view not fullscreen

Tags: iphone, objective-c, view, uiview

I was looking for answer in other questions but found out it's impossible to play video in iPhone in a view and not fullscreen, but maybe it has changed with the new versions? Somebody knows anything?

Comment: Sentence 3 from the Apple docs: `When you add a movie player’s view to your app’s view hierarchy, be sure to size the frame correctly, as shown here:`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use MPMoviePlayerController for playing the video and set the frame where you want to display it in the layout.

```
// Create custom movie player
MPMoviePlayerController *moviePlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:URL];

[moviePlayer setControlStyle:MPMovieControlStyleNone];

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
 addObserver:self
 selector:@selector(onMSAASDone:)
 name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification
 object:moviePlayer];

[moviePlayer setScalingMode:MPMovieScalingModeAspectFill];
[moviePlayer setFullscreen:FALSE];

//---play partial screen---
moviePlayer.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 300);
[self.view addSubview:moviePlayer.view];
```